# Cufon and JQuery selecting list element

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, cufon

I'm using wordpress, JQuery and Cufon and I have this one problem.

Cufon automatically selects all the child elements of a list. So JQuery and Cufon
selecting works differently. Here is an example:

In JQuery I can do it like this:

```
    $("#example > ul > li").css("color", "red");
```

And it changes only the top list elements' texts to red (Title1, Title2, Title3).

But when I try the same type of selector in Cufon it changes also the sublist element's fonts (Title1, Title2, Title3, Subtitle1, Subtitle2..).

```
    <html>
    <head><title>Example</title></head>
    <body>
        <ul id="example">
            <li>
                Tittle1
                <ul>
                    <li>Subtitle1</li>
                    <li>Subtitle2</li>
                    <li>Subtitle3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Tittle2
                <ul>
                    <li>Subtitle1</li>
                    <li>Subtitle2</li>
                    <li>Subtitle3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Tittle3
                <ul>
                    <li>Subtitle1</li>
                    <li>Subtitle2</li>
                    <li>Subtitle3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Well I could wrap the Title1 etc. in span elements but I`m using Wordpress and it automatically builds all those lists so I dont want to go and changes them.